# HTaccess level error returning Bad Request

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Here is my htaccess configuration for apache...

```
DocumentRoot /opt/api/

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule /v1/(.*)$ /v1/api.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

This seems to be bringing back the error...

```
Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

My file structure is '/opt/api/v1/api.php'. I'm assuming this is an error at the htaccess level since I am not receiving any returns in my error log.

Any ideas that can lead me in the right direction?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with the rewrite rules specifically but what I mention below, however you can not use `DocumentRoot` directive in .htaccess. That goes in the server config.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot

Also your rule will probably not match because of the leading `/` in the rewriterule which in .htaccess per directory context, it will be removed before matching. Try the rules this way. Providing the .htaccess file is in the root directory.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^v1/(.*)$ /v1/api.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```